# logging in continouous loop

Tags: python, logging

What would be a good way to create logs (with python logging module) inside a constant running loop, without producing a large amount of useless log-files?
An example would be a loop that constant list a folder, and does some action when it sees a file of a specific type.
I want to log that no files were found, or files were found but of a wrong type, without logging that same line constantly for each folder check, as it might run many times a second.

Comment: Are you looking for "if" statement?

Comment: Please, try to explain it better.

Comment: Could you clarify your questions please... So would you like to have it log, say, every 500 times through the loop? Or do you want to it to log only if the message has changed?

Comment: Are you just wanting to remove consecutive duplicates? I.e., only log when the status changes?

Comment: Yes, removing consecutive duplicates would be a good solution. 
Another would be based on time.
It just seems like something that must have an elegant solution, rather then having to keep track of specific states in the loop, and what was logged in the last loop

Comment: I'm adding some keywords to help search for this question: allow logging a message only once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a [`Handler`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/logging.html#handler-objects) that subclasses whatever other functionality you need. Store either the last, or all the previously logged messages that you don't want to [`emit`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/logging.html#logging.Handler.emit) again:

```
def make_filetype_aware_handler(handler_class):
    class DontRepeatFiletypeHandler(handler_class):

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwds)
            self.previous_types = set()

        def emit(self, record):
            if not record.file_type in self.previous_types:
                self.previous_types.add(record.file_type)
                super().emit(record)
    return DontRepeatFiletypeHandler

FiletypeStreamHandler = make_filetype_aware_handler(logging.StreamHandler)

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.addHandler(FiletypeStreamHandler(sys.stderr))
logger.debug('Found file of type %(file_type)', file_type='x-type/zomg')
```

Comment: Thanks! Guess I could also check for messages that are the same or very much a-like.

Comment: @Mikkel Jans: Yes, that's quite a common way to log. Repeated messages will be replaced with "Message repeated X times". You could easily have a "last message" placeholder, and a counter. When the message changes, dump an extra log item with the consecutive count of the previous.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you are trying to limit logging the same message over and over again.

If this is your issue, I would create a a set of file_types you have already logged.  However you need to be careful, if this is going to run forever, you will eventually crash..

```
from sets import Set
logged = Set()
while yourCondition:
   file_type = get_next_file_type()
   needToLog = #determine if you need to log this thing

   if needToLog and (not file_type in logged):
      logger.info("BAH! " + file_type)
      logged.add(file_type)
```

Comment: So many parens you've got there, is that in LISP? :P This code gives me: NameError: name 'Set' is not defined

Comment: @Rosh Oxymoron that help?  Its python psuedo code :)  parens help keep things organized for me ;).  Like the name ;).

Answer (score 0):

Log the less important events with a lower precedence, like DEBUG. See [setLevel](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.setLevel) and [SysLogHandler](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.handlers.html#sysloghandler).

At development time set the level to DEBUG, and as your application matures, set it to more reasonable values like INFO or ERROR.

Your app should do something about the errors, like remove files of the wrong type and/or create lacking files; or move the wrongfully configured directories from the job polling to a quarantine location, so your log will not be flooded.

Answer (score 0):

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(test)
# logging to a file
hdlr = logging.FileHandler(test.log)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(filename)s %(lineno)s %(levelname)s %    (message)s')
hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(hdlr) 
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Then in the loop, you have to check for file type and if file is present or not.
Then add :

```
logger.debug('File Type : %s ' % file_type)
```

also

```
if file_present:
    logger.debug('File Present : %s ' % present)
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hack but much easier is "misusing" `functools` [lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache).

```py
from functools import lru_cache
from logging import getLogger

# Keep track of 10 different messages and then warn again
@lru_cache(10)
def warn_once(logger: Logger, msg: str):
    logger.warning(msg)
```

You can increase the `10` to suppress more if required or set it to `None` to store suppress everything duplicated.